# How does service discovery work for pods with hostNetwork=true

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

If the hostNetwork is set to true in pod spec, it receives the same IP address as host. While the pod can be reached at with this ip, I am not able to reach the pod through a service. If I set the clusterIP to None in service, the dns lookup doesn't return any results. If a clusterIP is assigned, traffic is not redirected to the backend pod.

Answer (score 1):

(definitely wrong, misunderstood the question)
The problem is in /etc/resolv.conf

When using hostNetwork=true you get host's dns servers and you don't have cluster dns there.

[Track issue on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17406)

Comment: I think that issue is about hostNetworked services discover the nonHostNetworked service. My question is how does a regular pod send traffic to hostNetworked pod through the service abstraction?

Comment: Oh, you are right. Misunderstood your question.

You may try to manually create an endpoint for your service and point it to the host ip.

Comment: I did similar thing with 2 different solutions, one is to create a k8s deployment to proxy request to host network IPs (using nginx as it's an HTTP service), the other one, I use externalName (check http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#services-without-selectors).